# JavaScript copy to clipboard: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

So I've got this line of code:

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText("test");
```

And I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText')`

What do I do? Do I need to establish or create a clipboard object before this somehow?

Comment: What browser and version is this?